# Mean of every 3 columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
            2016-01    2016-02    2016-03    2016-04    2016-05    2016-06 ....
    name

    John    1000       1500       1800        2000       1600       1000
```

Except it has 10730 entries. What i would want is to have a new DataFrame with the mean of every quarter of the year (3 months). for example:

```
        2016q1    2016q2    .....
John    143.333   1533.333
```

My solution to this is horrible and taking too much time, so anything is better. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert to datetime then `resample`

```
df.columns=pd.to_datetime(df.columns,format='%Y-%m')
df
Out[7]: 
      2016-01-01  2016-02-01  2016-03-01  2016-04-01  2016-05-01  2016-06-01
John        1000        1500        1800        2000        1600        1000
df=df.resample('Q',axis=1).mean()
df.columns=pd.PeriodIndex(df.columns, freq='Q')
df
Out[14]: 
           2016Q1       2016Q2
John  1433.333333  1533.333333
```

Comment: I thought too much and created a dict based on repeated range for grouping . Nice one.

Comment: @Dark aha, dict is also a good way , since that is much customize :-)

Comment: Hi @Wen, thanks for the quick response and sorry for my slow one. That worked perfectly, thank you!

Comment: @EliasUhalde yw ~ :-) happy coding